# How to show a specific message in an alert depending on the data-id attribute of a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a specific message when a user clicks on a download button but the value depends of the data-id.

This is what i have so far:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li className="col rats"><a title="Rats" href="#rats" data-id="rats" id="ratsDownload">
<li className="col frogss"><a title="Frogs" href="#frogs" data-id="frogs" id="frogsDownload">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Download!</button>

<script>
 function show(){
var idOne = document.getElementById('ratsDownload');
var idTwo = document.getElementById('frogsDownload');

 var Val = rats.getAttribute('data-id');
 var Val2 = frogs.getAttribute('data-id');
   
  if(Val==rats){
    alert("5");
}

 if(Val2==frogs){
    alert("9");
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you define the variables `rats` and `frogs`?  You seem to be expecting them to be both HTML elements *and* strings.  They can only be one or the other, but currently they are neither because you haven't defined them.

Comment: Wrap rats in and frogs in quotes "rats"

Comment: David, I am trying to get the value of data-id to define the value rats and frogs. I mean what I want to do is: if the data-id ="x" --> alert("Y"); if the data-id="z"--> alert("W"); but I don't know how to do it!! :(

Comment: @KittenHustler: Don't just give up and ask the community to do your work for you.  Focus on the work you've already done and examine/test/debug it.  Your browser has debugging tools that are very helpful in this regard.  The console in those debugging tools is showing errors.  Pay attention to those errors.  The first error you should be seeing is that `rats` is undefined.  Because it isn't defined.  So when you do `rats.getAttribute('data-id')` what are you expecting as a result and why?  Continue this process with each error or each line of code.

Comment: ^ what imvain2 stated! To correctly compare the equality of variable `Val` with `rats` (which is not a defined variable anywhere in your code or a string). You must make `rats` a String type like `Val == "rats"`.

Comment: @KittenHustler If you want to access data-attributes. Just use `document.querySelector("#ratsDownload").dataset.id` to get the value of `data-id`

Comment: I will try this approach Tanner and add the quotes! Thanks!

Comment: The combined approach of @TannerDolby and adding up the " " to wrap the string it was useful for me. No guys, I  was not hoping to get the work done for me, I am LEARNING from other ones, as you did when you were a junior. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<ul>
<li className="col rats"><a title="Rats" href="#rats" data-id="rats" id="ratsDownload">
<li className="col frogss"><a title="Frogs" href="#frogs" data-id="frogs" id="frogsDownload">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="show()">Download!</button>

<script>
 function show(){

var idOne = document.getElementById('ratsDownload');
var idTwo = document.getElementById('frogsDownload');

 var Val = idOne.getAttribute('data-id');
 var Val2 = idTwo.getAttribute('data-id');
   
  if(Val==="rats"){
    alert("5");
}

 if(Val2==="frogs"){
    alert("9");
}
}

</script>
```